# Tomcat takes too much time to start - Java SecureRandom

Tags: java, security, amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

Please don't mark it as duplicate. It is a follow up question for both these questions.

- [Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 [Digitalocean]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325109/6785908

I understand that, replacing

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

with

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

in `$JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security` will solve this problem.

My question is, is it ok to do so in production? Will this have any impact on security (like Session ID becoming predictable)? If this is less secure, is there any other way to give enough entropy quicker?

## Update

I use openstack for deployment (or let's just say, uses AWS or GCP or any other cloud provider). So, adding a hardware device such as soundcard is not an option for me.

Comment: _"Will this have any impact on security"_ - yes, it will not be as random as `SecureRandom`. It's up to you to decide if that's sufficient for your production use.

Comment: What you really need is a decent source of entropy. You can buy hardware noise-makers that can be used for this purpose. Note that this isn't a problem with Tomcat or Java... it's a problem with properly-done crypto (and you shouldn't work-around it).

Comment: @random-dude This is worth a read: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some extensive Googling with the right search terms, I came across this nice article on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged). I am merely quoting the relevant part here.

> There are two general random devices on Linux: /dev/random and
>   /dev/urandom. The best randomness comes from /dev/random, since it's a
>   blocking device, and will wait until sufficient entropy is available
>   to continue providing output. Assuming your entropy is sufficient, you
>   should see the same quality of randomness from /dev/urandom; however,
>   since it's a non-blocking device, it will continue producing “random”
>   data, even when the entropy pool runs out. This can result in lower
>   quality random data, as repeats of previous data are much more likely.
>   Lots of bad things can happen when the available entropy runs low on a
>   production server, especially when this server performs cryptographic
>   functions.

So, its a potential security risk.

### Solution for Populating Entropy Pools

> Linux already gets very good quality random data from the
>   different hardware sources, but since a headless machine usually
>   has no keyboard or mouse, there is much less entropy generated. Disk
>   and network I/O represent the majority of entropy generation sources
>   for these machines, and these produce very sparse amounts of entropy.
>   Since very few headless machines like servers or cloud servers/virtual
>   machines have any sort of dedicated hardware RNG solution available,
>   there exist several userland solutions to generate additional entropy
>   using hardware interrupts from devices that are “noisier” than hard
>   disks, like video cards, sound cards, etc. This once again proves to
>   be an issue for servers unfortunately, as they do not commonly contain
>   either one

### Solution: haveged

> Based on the HAVEGE principle, and previously based on its associated
>   library, haveged allows generating randomness based on variations in
>   code execution time on a processor. Since it's nearly impossible for
>   one piece of code to take the same exact time to execute, even in the
>   same environment on the same hardware, the timing of running a single
>   or multiple programs should be suitable to seed a random source. The
>   haveged implementation seeds your system's random source (usually
>   /dev/random) using differences in your processor's time stamp counter
>   (TSC) after executing a loop repeatedly

### How to install haveged

Follow the steps in this article. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged

Comment: I believe the article falls victim to the traditional misunderstanding of how `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` calculate (really, _estimate_) available entropy. Please take a look at [Myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/#low-entropy) to understand this. There are concerns that haveged is [not suitable/helpful for generating](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/34552/16485) [entropy](https://lwn.net/Articles/525459/).

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the linked article! Btw, the anchor was modified in the meantime, and the link is now https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/#what-about-entropy-running-low